# One dimensional vector space and not Hausdorff

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

I read that all vector spaces that do not have the Hausdorff property and are one-dimensional need to have the trivial topology. I am not quite sure how to approach this problem, but I would like to get an idea, how we can show this?-Somehow I assume that this problem should not be too hard, so I would be glad about any possible hint.

Thus, either full solutions or ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: I think he means a topological vector space, i.e addition and scalar multiplication are continuous

Comment: yep and I talk about one-dimensional vector spaces, which are almost sure finite dimensional ;-)

Comment: I think studiosus means finite cardinal and you are talking about finite dimension^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $E$ is a topological vector space over a field $K$ who does not have trivial topology, i.e there is an open set $O$ different from $E$ and $\emptyset$. Choose $x\in O$ and $y\notin O$. Consider, for all $k\in K^{*}$, the continuous function $f_{k}:v\mapsto x+k^{-1}(v-x)$. Then $O_{k}=f_{k}^{-1}(O)$ is open, contains $x$, and does not contain $x+k(y-x)$ since $f_{k}(x+k(y-x))=y$.

If $E$ is one-dimensional, every $z\in E\setminus\{x\}$ can be written $x+k_{0}(y-x)$ for some $k_{0}$, and then $O_{k_{0}}$ separates $x$ from $z$. This shows $x$ can be separated from every other point in $E$. To show that for general $x'\in E$ do the reasoning above again with $O'= O+(x'-x)$, which is open again by continuity of addition.

Comment: Actually this only shows $E$ is $T_{1}$ and not $T_{2}$ (what is usually called Hausdorff) and I don't know yet how to complete the argument.

Comment: for a topological vector space I think we generally have that $\{0\}$  is  closed which is $T_1$ if and only if the space is Hausdorff.

Comment: Well then here $\{0\}$ is surely closed since the $\bigcup_{y\in E\setminus\{0\}} O_{y}= E\setminus\{0\}$ is open, with $O_{y}$ being an open set containing $y$ but not $0$. How do you prove your statement though ?

Comment: Suppose that $V$ is an open nbhd of $0$ in $E$. There is a symmetric open nbhd $W$ of $0$ such that $W+W\subseteq V$. (This is essentially just continuity of vector addition and additive inverse.) If $x\in\operatorname{cl}W$, then $W\cap(x-W)=W\cap(x+W)\ne\varnothing$, so there are $w_0,w_1\in W$ such that $x=w_0+w_1\in W+W\subseteq V$, so $0\in W\subseteq\operatorname{cl}W\subseteq V$. This argument can be translated to any point of $E$, so $E$ is regular. You’ve shown that $E$ is $T_1$, so $E$ is $T_3$ and therefore Hausdorff. This works in any topological group.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the anwser ! I don't get everything in it but I'll try to sort that out

Answer (score 0):

Let's make the framework explicit. We have a topological field $K$ and a topological vector space $V$; this means that the addition operations $K\times K\to K$ and $V\times V\to V$, as well as the multiplication operations $K\times K\to K$ and $K\times V\to V$, are continuous. Also taking opposites in $K$ and $V$ as well as $\alpha\to\alpha^{-1}$ defined on $K\setminus\{0\}$ must be continuous.

By continuity, the neighborhoods of $x\in V$ are the subsets of the form $x+U$, where $U$ is a neighborhood of $0$ (the map $v\mapsto x+v$ is a homeomorphism).

If $\{0\}$ is closed in $V$, then $V$ is Hausdorff. Indeed, let $x\ne 0$ and consider a neighborhood of $0$ such that $x\notin U$. Then there exists a neighborhood $U'$ of $0$ such that $U'-U'\subseteq U$. If $v\in U'\cap(x+U')$, then $v=x+v'$ for some $v'\in U'$, so $x=v-v'\in U'-U'$, which is a contradiction.

Thus $U'\cap(x+U')=\emptyset$. Using translations, we have proved that $V$ is Hausdorff.

Now, again by continuity, the closure of a subspace is again a subspace (use nets, as it's easier).

If $V$ is one dimensional and $\{0\}$ is not closed, its closure must be $V$. Thus the only closed set containing $0$ is $V$. So the only open set not containing $0$ is the empty set. If $A$ is a proper open set and $v\notin A$, then $0\notin -v+A$, so $-v+A=\emptyset$ and $A=\emptyset$.